# Scrapy PyInstaller OSError: could not get source code / twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pyinstaller, twisted

I am trying to publish a very simple Scrapy spider as an EXE file using PyInstaller.

I have searched and read everything I could find, but I still can’t figure out what is going wrong. How can I fix this?

If I change the yield to return it doesn't give me the error and works except for it only returning one item (which is normal since it is a return and not a yield.) the code works just fine without any errors in my IDE (not using the PyInstaller EXE file).

Note:
I am using PyInstaller development version.

Error when running my EXE file:

```
2020-04-28 11:57:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://books.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 42, in process_request
  File "lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1362, in returnValue
twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 http://books.toscrape.com/>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 55, in mustbe_deferred
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 60, in process_spider_input
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 148, in call_spider
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 202, in warn_on_generator_with_return_value
  File "lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 187, in is_generator_with_return_value
  File "inspect.py", line 973, in getsource
  File "inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code
```

#### File *myBookSpider.py*

```
import scrapy
from items import scrapyStandaloneTestItem

class bookSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "bookSpider"
    custom_settings = {
        "FEED_URI": "resultFile.csv",
        "FEED_FORMAT": "csv",
        "FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS": ["title", "price"]
    }

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = [
            "http://books.toscrape.com/",
        ]

        for url in urls:

            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        # Getting an instance of our item class
        item = scrapyStandaloneTestItem()

        # Getting all the article's with product pod class
        articles = response.css("article.product_pod")

        # Looping through all the article elements we got earlier
        for article in articles:

            # Getting the needed values from the site and putting them in variables
            title = article.css("a::attr(title)").extract()
            price = article.css("p.price_color::text").extract()

            # Setting the title / price variables in our items class equal to the variables that we just extracted data in to
            item["title"] = title
            item["price"] = price
            yield item
```

#### File *items.py*

```
import scrapy

class scrapyStandaloneTestItem(scrapy.Item):

    # Define the fields for your item here
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

#### File *runSpider.py*

```
# In this file we will run the spider(s)
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from myBookSpider import bookSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def runSpider():

    # Running scraper
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(bookSpider)
    process.start()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):

    runSpider()
```

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: same problem in "Scrapy 2.4.1"

Comment: @PATAPOsha Still working on it

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is to add this code into your spider:

```
import scrapy.utils.misc
import scrapy.core.scraper

def warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub(spider, callable):
    pass

scrapy.utils.misc.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub
scrapy.core.scraper.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub
```