# Error after running .exe file originating from scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy, pyinstaller

I am writing a scrapy project which works perfectly. I have converted it to an executable using pyinstaller. Now I was expecting some trouble as to importing modules as I have read that a lot of people are having trouble with that. But for some reason I don't even get that far. As soon as I run the main.exe file, the console opens up and shows the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "rascraper\main.py", line 1,

This is the corresponding main.py file

```
from rascraper.spiders.spiderone import PostsSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def main():

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(PostsSpider)
    process.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And This is my spider class

```
import scrapy


class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'posts'

    # artist = input(f'Artist Name:')
    # filter = input(f'filter on Country? (y/n):')
    #
    # if filter == 'y':
    #     country = input(f'Country:')
    #     start_urls = [
    #         f'https://ra.co/dj/{artist}/past-events?country={country}'
    #     ]
    #
    # elif filter == 'n':
    #     start_urls = [
    #         f'https://ra.co/dj/{artist}/past-events'
    #     ]

    HEADERS = {
        'accept': '/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6',
        'authorization': 'df67dacc9c704696b908a618dd4f59be',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'origin': 'https://ra.co',
        'referer': 'https://ra.co/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    }


    def parse(self, response):

        for post in response.css('li.Column-sc-18hsrnn-0.inVJeD'):

            date = post.css('.Text-sc-1t0gn2o-0.jmZufm::text').get()
            event = post.css('.Text-sc-1t0gn2o-0.Link__StyledLink-k7o46r-0.dXQVFW::text').get()
            location = post.css('.Text-sc-1t0gn2o-0.Link__StyledLink-k7o46r-0.echVma::text').get()
            venue = post.css('.Text-sc-1t0gn2o-0.Link__StyledLink-k7o46r-0.dxNiKF::text').get()
            acts = post.css('.Text-sc-1t0gn2o-0.bYvpkM::text').get()

            item = {}
            item['Date'] = date
            item['Event'] = event
            item['Location'] = location
            item['Venue'] = venue
            item['Acts'] = acts

            yield item
```

Where does this error come from and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hello. Please do not use image to show code/errors. Also, this stacktrace provides no information at all.

Comment: @Itération122442 Thank you, I have edited the question. However, the problem that it provides no information at all is kind of my problem as well. It suggests that the problem is in "PostsSpider" right?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331478/how-to-create-a-single-executable-file-in-windows-10-with-scrapy-and-pyinstaller/55339170#55339170 answer your question. Possibility to anyhow convert scrapy application into windows executable - has never been planned by scrapy creators and maintainers

Comment: You should definitely be seeing more than this from a stack trace. Even supposing the error is directly there at `rascraper\main.py, line 1`, it should have echoed that line of code back to you (like `from rascraper.spiders.spiderone import PostsSpider`, and stated a type of error with a message (such as the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rascraper/settings.py'` bit you mentioned in a comment on an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Making a standalone executable from scrapy project with PyInstaller**

In order to create a single executable file you'll need to do the following steps:

1. Add this to all of your spiders ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478001/scrapy-pyinstaller-oserror-could-not-get-source-code-twisted-internet-defer)):

```py
import scrapy.utils.misc
import scrapy.core.scraper


def warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub(spider, callable):
    pass


scrapy.utils.misc.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub
scrapy.core.scraper.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub
```

So in my example `spider.py` will look like this:

```py
import scrapy
import scrapy.utils.misc
import scrapy.core.scraper


def warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub(spider, callable):
    pass


scrapy.utils.misc.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub
scrapy.core.scraper.warn_on_generator_with_return_value = warn_on_generator_with_return_value_stub


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()
        yield item
```

2. Add this to `main.py` (if you don't add this then you'll get error whenever you try to run the executable from a directory outside of your project's directory):

```py
import os

os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', PATH_TO_SETTINGS)
```

In this example `main.py`:

```py
import os
from rascraper.spiders.spider import ExampleSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(ExampleSpider)
    process.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

3. Run pyinstaller to generate a spec file: `python -m PyInstaller --onefile --name example_exe main.py`.
4. Change the spec file: Add all the files in your project to `datas` list.

Before:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='example_exe',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

After:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('items.py','.'),
                    ('middlewares.py','.'),
                    ('pipelines.py','.'),
                    ('settings.py','.'),
                    ('spiders','spiders'),
                    ('..\\scrapy.cfg', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='example_exe',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

5. Build the spec file: `python -m PyInstaller example_exe.spec`

**Result:**

Now should have a standalone executable that you can run in any directory:

```
C:\Users\MY_USER\Desktop>example_exe.exe

...
...
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/>
{'title': 'Long-sleeved Jersey Top', 'price': '$12.99'}
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
...
...
```

**Specifically for OP's project:**

The project tree looks like this:

```
C:.
│   main.py
│   scrapy.cfg
│
└───rascraper
    │   items.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   settings.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───spiders
    │   │   spiderone.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │           spiderone.cpython-310.pyc
    │           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │
    └───__pycache__
            middlewares.cpython-310.pyc
            pipelines.cpython-310.pyc
            settings.cpython-310.pyc
            __init__.cpython-310.pyc
```

So the `datas` list should be:

```py
datas=[('rascraper\\items.py', '.'),
       ('rascraper\\middlewares.py', '.'),
        ('rascraper\\pipelines.py', '.'),
        ('rascraper\\settings.py', '.'),
        ('rascraper\\spiders', 'spiders'),
        ('scrapy.cfg', '.')],
```

**Correction:** In `main.py` it should just be `os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I run the .exe file, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rascraper/settings.py'". (I specified this path as step two of your answer) I have a folder with build, dist, scrapy.cfg, main.py and the package 'rascraper'. In the package 'rascraper' I have the package 'spiders' and the files: init, items, middleware, pipelines and settings. Do you know what the correct path is if that is what went wrong?

Comment: I have tried that as well and added ('rascraper/settings.py', 'settings') to the data list. Also tried '.' and 'rascraper/settings' for the last bit. None of it worked. Could it be that my project directories are a bit messed up?

Comment: Can you share the project so I can try it myself?

Comment: That would be amazing! What is the best way to do so? email or git or something?

Comment: Just upload it to some temporary archive website and I'll download it.

Comment: I have uploaded it to github. This is the link. Thank you in advance.https://github.com/AxelZoons/rascraper.git

Comment: @AxelotlZ I checked with my spider for simplicity and it works. See the update.