# I am trying to build an EXE file from PyInstaller for a Scrapy app

Tags: python, compiler-errors, scrapy, syntax-error, pyinstaller

I get the error 'tuple index out of range' and am very confused what is causing this issue.

The Python code runs fine, and I am only getting an error compiling it in PyInstaller.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM2QM.png)

Comment: @MiguelMLR9 your answer in a different post helped solve this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059771/17575122

However, my application file opens and does not run as expected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70587390/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved using these two other answers:

*[How can I create a single executable file in Windows 10 with Scrapy and PyInstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331478/how-to-create-a-single-executable-file-in-windows-10-with-scrapy-and-pyinstaller/55339170#55339170)*

*[Scrapy PyInstaller OSError: could not get source code / twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478001/scrapy-pyinstaller-oserror-could-not-get-source-code-twisted-internet-defer)*

The issue seems to happen only for the Python 3.10 version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and solved it by upgrading Python to version 3.10.2.

This issue is fixed in Python version 3.10.1 and later.